# What are the avenues for attack in Sanctuary Hill?

Tags: fallout-4

I've only just started the settlement here and I'm wondering what the possible attack angles are. I would wager that the bridge is one potential attack direction but are there more? There's another significant gap between some bushes that seems like it warrants defending but I want to make sure before expending resources to do so. I'm especially worried that attackers will ignore the pseudo-moat and attack from any direction...

Comment: Considering that you don't get back all the resources you use to build, I'd be interested in this too so I don't waste resources.

Comment: I took about 60 hours to play through the game on Normal, and Sanctuary was *never* attacked. I kept the defense >= to the food + water pretty much the whole time. About halfway through a playthrough on Hard, I still have never had an attack on Sanctuary. Get your defense number up, and you probably don't need to worry too much.

Comment: I've never been particularly worried about getting attacked (my defense is over double the cumulative total of my food/water), I asked the question so I can focus defenses in particular places instead of blanket-turreting my entire settlement (which I have done at this point).

Answer (score 9):

I believe there are 3, the Bridge for Raiders, the Vault path area for Supermutants, and Water for mirelurks. I've only got around 15 hours in the game so there may be more. It's worth noting that on my first character I was never attacked there, it only happened after I bumped the difficulty up.

Comment: Have you managed to gather any more insight into this? If you can confirm that there are the three you mentioned (plus the one that Li Jiru mentioned) I will go ahead and mark this the answer.

Comment: I've seen a few comments around the net saying the same thing, the two bridge approaches and near the Southern bridge (towards Red Rocket) across the shallow water. My experience in over 100 hours of gameplay bears this out.
Walls/fences are mostly a waste, as NPCs can 'teleport'. I've had them appear inside the walled area very frequently. Protect your resources and settlers with elevated turrets. The Wooden 'bridge' is great for this. Turrets 'scan' about 120 degrees, so three of them can 'see' 360 degrees. Once an enemy has been detected, the turrets can track them all around.

Answer (score 3):

Too add to what was said there seems to be another route. Coming out of your original house to the left side of sanctuary. Was literally just attacked moments ago by ferals coming from that direction

Answer (score 3):

You can be attacked from anywhere TECHNICALLY. However, if you put up your defences correctly you will only be attacked in the previously mentioned area. Put up a ring of guard outposts and turrets. If you do this you will only be attacked in the conventional routes. Then make a focus of turrets and traps in the previously mentioned routes. Also, put bells next to the stands. Place spotlights on these previous mentioned places as well. MAKE SURE TO HOOK UP YOUR TRAPS TO A SWITCH! Every time they are used they have to be repaired. If you just hook them up to power they go off immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I built a wall around the entire settlement except the bridge and nothing attacks me

Answer (score -1):

Really if you have enough defense then you won't be atacked but i suggest making a wall around the house with the workshop and set gates and watchtowers with turrets a nod then you will be prepared for any stack from any direction